# Check if current and external .Net process has performance counters enabled?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection, performancecounter

In C# or else VB.Net, and having only a **PID** of a process, I wonder if it can be possibly to check at execution time whether the associated process has performance counters enabled.

I'll mean when the `performanceCounters` setting is enabled in its **app.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
...
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <performanceCounters enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
...
</configuration>
```

However, I'm asking about the possible existance of a proper/built-in solution using reflection, or other .Net Framework members than doing a primitive check for an **app.config** file and then parsing the file to find the setting, I'm aware of that, its what I'm trying to avoid.

As a secondary question I will ask:

How I could check for the same thing in the current process?, 
I ask this because maybe the methodology to determine whether performance counters are enabled in the current process could be easier than determining it in an external process (but again I'm asking this for a solution to avoid parsing the **app.config** file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specifically want to avoid parsing the app.config file, but frankly I would. Your question suggest you don't want to "manually" parse the app.config, which you don't have to (So I'll be stubborn on suggest the following ;-))

Check for the current process:

```
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var group = (NetSectionGroup)config.GetSectionGroup("system.net");
        if (group.Settings.PerformanceCounters.Enabled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ENABLED");
        }
```

Check for other processes, well executables really.

```
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(@" ... path to other executable ... ");
        var group = (NetSectionGroup)config.GetSectionGroup("system.net");
        if (group.Settings.PerformanceCounters.Enabled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ENABLED");
        }
```

Comment: I love this answer, I discovered the powerful of that `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class, thanks a lot. (waiting for StackOverflow security period to be able to give bounty reward)

Answer (score 1):

Usually all per-process Performance Counters have PID (or process name or some other identifying information) embedded in Performance Counters Instance Names:

[image]

(the part highlighted in yellow is the PID).

So if Process ID is what you have, you can search around instance names for this substring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but to be able to see the instance names of "X" **PerformanceCounterCategory** I think the app also needs to have at least 1 counter running (not just the performancecounters setting enabled) which differs from my question. correct me if I'm wrong. thanks again!.

Comment: @ElektroStudios For a performance counter for a particular PID to exist, this process (the app itself) should be running, true.

Answer (score 0):

I did this Generic usage function for future needs with App config file, maybe it will not be able to parse the tree level  architecture in all scenarios, but hey, its just a start.

Usage:

```
 GetAppConfigSetting(Of Boolean)("system.net", "settings", "performanceCounters", "enabled"))
```

Source:

```
Public Shared Function GetAppConfigSetting(Of T)(ByVal sectionGroupName As String,
                                                 ByVal sectionName As String,
                                                 ByVal elementName As String,
                                                 ByVal propertyName As String,
                                                 Optional ByVal exePath As String = "") As T

    Dim appConfig As Configuration
    Dim group As ConfigurationSectionGroup
    Dim section As ConfigurationSection
    Dim sectionPropInfo As PropertyInformation
    Dim element As ConfigurationElement
    Dim elementPropInfo As PropertyInformation

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(exePath) Then
        appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath)
    Else
        appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    End If

    group = appConfig.GetSectionGroup(sectionGroupName)
    If group Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    section = group.Sections(sectionName)
    If section Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    sectionPropInfo = section.ElementInformation.Properties(elementName)
    If sectionPropInfo Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    element = DirectCast(sectionPropInfo.Value, ConfigurationElement)
    If element Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    elementPropInfo = element.ElementInformation.Properties(propertyName)
    If elementPropInfo Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Return DirectCast(elementPropInfo.Value, T)

End Function
```